Can I make a tire swing with no initial angular momentum spin while swinging?
Is it possible to make a tire swing with no initial angular momentum spin while swinging?
One way to make it spin while not swinging is to rotate an arm in succession around the three axes; this will cause the swing to rotate when the arm is rotating around the spinning (i.e. vertical) axis due to conservation of angular momentum, whereas rotating the arm around the other two axes will have no effect, but will return the arm to the initial position allowing the swinger to keep swinging in the same direction as long as he's making the movement.
I wonder if there's another way to spin -- first, swinging can be initiated in normal swinging fashion by shifting weight back and forth; now we have a pendulum that has angular momentum that is oscillating over time; technically by shifting his weight or changing body position, the swinger can alter his moment of inertia tensor, therefore entering precession and spinning around a second axis; the swinger would need to shift the weight the opposite way when the swing changes direction to keep spinning the same way.
Is this possible? Or is any other variation of this possible? Is there a video demonstration of it somewhere, or an article discussing it? I just tried doing the experiment, but I couldn't get it to spin. Thanks!

On a tire swing hanging from a single 'perfect' torsion-less rope, it is not possible to initiate a spin about the axis of the rope as that would break the law of conservation of angular momentum. So to answer your specific question - it is thus impossible to transfer your linear swinging motion into a spinning motion.
With regards to 'making it spin [by rotating arms]', there is no net angular motion onduced into the system. Unlike pumping a swing, in which the swing and rider retains linear momentum when they stop pumping, the nett 'spin' of the swing and rider will stop the instant that the arm motions cease. Rather than imparting spin, you are just changing your (and the swing's) relative orientation while moving your arms.
If your tire hangs from two separated ropes, or if the single rope can transmit torsion forces along its length, then it is possible to ititiate a spin by rotational 'pumping' (i.e. a similar action to that you would use to start a stationary swing swinging).
With regards to utilizing your swinging motion to initiate a change in the direction you are pointing in (i.e. a change in orientation but not a continuous roation over time). When you are at the bottom of the swing path, you have relative rotational motion about a horizontal axis that is perpendiculat to your path of motion. So if you apply a force that attempts to rotate that axis in the vertical plane there will be a gyroscopic precession in the horizontal plane that might reorient you (say from North to North-West). That might work if, for example, you stuck one leg out sideways below your centre of mass. But your rotational motion is very slow so I imagine that the precession angle would be extroadinarily small.

In my second paragraph I already mentioned one way to make it spin which is theoretically sound and have experimentally checked to be true. The question is, can I do it by swinging making use of precession?

See my edit - in your description of the arm rotation technique, you are not actually imparting any net angular momentum. You could similarly 'spin' if you held a heavy wheel with its axis oriented vertically and started to rotate the wheel clockwise. You, and the swing would counter-rotate anticlockwise and will continue doing so as long as the wheel keeps rotatig clockwise, but there is no net angular momentum. The moment the wheel stops rotating, you will also stop rotating.

Newton's first Law states that it is not possible.

@Penguino But lacking a wheel, can I still do it somehow? Like, with my own body? :) Yes, by "spin" I mean change orientation while I'm moving (though orientation isn't a well-defined concept for non-rigid bodies; but spin also doesn't have an official meaning in physics outside quantum physics I believe)

@Narasimham Note how Newton's Laws don't distinguish between internal and external forces; once you see the swinger's body (informal language) as composed of multiple bodies (physics definition), then moving one's arm indeed creates forces. Since forces are present, we would expect the bodies (physics definition) to move, according to Newton's 1st.

@Gabi if by 'spin' you mean: 1) start motionless with your body (and the swing) oriented in one direction (lets assume facing North), 2) wave/move your arms/body appropriately, 3) end up, after a while, with your body and the swing now oriented in a different direction (say, facing South-West, for example), then yes, you can do that.  But if by 'spin' you mean spinning around in a circle (once the arm motion has stopped), as does a rotating top for example, then no, you can't do that.

@Penguino Yes, that's exactly what I mean! So it should be possible? Or there's some obscure phenomenon I don't know about that should prevent me? Is it discussed in any textbook or is there any video of it anywhere? I've failed to find anything, and I've failed the experiment today! (I did succeed the experiment I described in my 2nd paragraph). Can you help me please!? :)

@Gabi It may possible then. While you are at the bottom of the swing path, you have relative rotational motion about  a horizintal axis that is perpendiculat to your path of motion. So if you apply a force that attempts to rotate that axis in the vertical plane there will be a gyroscopic precession in the horizontal plane that should reorient you (say from North to North-West). That might work if, for example, you stuck one leg out sideways below your centre of mass. But your rotational motion is very slow so I imagine that the precession angle would be extroadinarily small.

@Penguino Thanks! So maybe I was rotating, but the change in angle was so small it was unnoticeable .. hmm I can probably compute how quickly I should be rotating ... somehow ... :) Also, do you want to add your last comment to your answer, then I can accept it ... ? :)

Indeed yes, muscular PE can get converted to KE.

@Penguino Actually, I've been thinking about the distinction between tire+rope vs tire+bars+hinge+swivel; while in the latter, it's possible to distribute the mass asymmetrically (in the way that matters for gyroscopic precession) and keep it there, with a rope, the center of mass will quickly move to directly under the point where the rope is attached, so the tensor of inertia matrix will be just slightly asymmetric (because my body shape on the tire is not symmetric), and the effect would be much smaller. What do you think?

While I can't ascertain that the tire will rotate on the rope-axis by a linear swing unless a force imparts an angular torque on the rope (twisting the tire), a linear swing -- North-to-South -- will theoretically evolve into a spherical swing by earth's Coriolis acceleration. You can calculate the motion of the tire from the earth's inertial reference frame. Neglecting Euler's force and centrifugal force, we can start out with, $$\vec{F}=-2m(\vec{\omega}\times \vec{v})$$
for an angular velocity vector, given your latitude $l$,
$$ \vec{\omega }=\mathbf{\omega }\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ cos(l) \\ sin(l)\end{bmatrix}$$
And the velocity components of the tire swinging within the earth's reference frame:
$$ \vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix} v_E \\ v_N \\ v_U \end{bmatrix}= velocity\begin{bmatrix} East \\ North \\ Up \end{bmatrix} $$
The acceleration vectors in the $N, E, U$ directions is:
$$ \vec{a_C}=-2\omega \left ( \vec{\omega}\times \vec{v} \right )=-2\omega \begin{bmatrix} v_U cos(l)- v_N sin(l) \\ v_E sin(l) \\ -v_E cos(l)\end{bmatrix}$$
Since there is no upward velocity and the upward acceleration is extremely small compared to the force of gravity, $a_C$ becomes,
$$ \vec{a_C}=\begin{bmatrix} 2\omega v_N sin(l) \\ -2\omega v_E sin(l) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
The total acceleration vector the tire experiences is,
$$ \vec{a_{total}}=\begin{bmatrix} 2\omega v_N sin(l) \\ -2\omega v_E sin(l) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} -\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ g \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2\omega v_N sin(l) \\ -2\omega v_E sin(l) \\ -g \end{bmatrix}$$

Where the tire's velocty components equal,
$ v_E = v_x = Lcos(\theta)cos(\phi)\frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} t}-Lsin(\theta)sin(\phi)\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi}{\mathrm{d} t}$
$ v_N = v_y = Lcos(\theta)sin(\phi)\frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} t}+ Lsin(\theta)cos(\phi)\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi}{\mathrm{d} t} $
$v_U = v_z = Lsin(\theta)\frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} t}$
and the potential energy of the tire is $V=mgL(1-cos(\theta))$.
The combined acceleration vectors, $a_E$ and $a_N$ with gravity $\vec{g}$, implies that the tire will deviate from a linear swing to a circular swing, thus $\phi(t)>0$ and the tire's trajectory will become elliptic.

Thanks! But will this cause me to face a different direction?
